# Cant get the value of an Edittext

Tags: android

hi i made a program that have `EditText`... i used for loop to set the number of my `EditText`, i cant get the value of my `EditText`(excellent), how can i do that? please help me..my output goes this way...

[image]

i want that 3,2,5,1,4 will display in my `EditText`,,

here are my codes...

```
  final TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
            table.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            table.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);



            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());             


            TextView txt = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt2 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt3 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt4 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt5 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
            TextView txt6 = new TextView (getApplicationContext());

            tableRow.addView(txt);
            tableRow.addView(txt2);
            tableRow.addView(txt3);
            tableRow.addView(txt4);
            tableRow.addView(txt5);
            tableRow.addView(txt6);



            tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            txt.setText("Question  ");
            txt2.setText("Excellent   ");
            txt3.setText("Best     ");
            txt4.setText("Better   ");
            txt5.setText("Good     ");
            txt6.setText("Poor     ");

            txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txt6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


            table.addView(tableRow);

            TableRow tableRow2 = null;
            EditText excellent = null;
            EditText best = null;
            EditText better = null;
            EditText good = null;
            EditText poor = null;

            TextView name = null;




            int j=0;
            for(j = 1; j<=count; j++){

                Random rnd = new Random(); 
                int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)); 

                 tableRow2  = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());
                 excellent = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                 best = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                 better = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                 good = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                 poor = new EditText (getApplicationContext());

                 name = new TextView (getApplicationContext());
                 //i want to retrive the value of this --->//excellent.setBackgroundColor(color);
                best.setBackgroundColor(color);
                better.setBackgroundColor(color);
                good.setBackgroundColor(color);
                poor.setBackgroundColor(color);


                name.setText("Q#"+Integer.toString(j));

                tableRow2.addView(name);
                tableRow2.addView(excellent);
                tableRow2.addView(best);
                tableRow2.addView(better);
                tableRow2.addView(good);
                tableRow2.addView(poor);
                table.addView(tableRow2);




            }
            final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            final String[]  a = excellent.getText().toString().split(",");
            output.append(a+",");



            TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow (getApplicationContext());

            Button get = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            tableRow1.addView(get);
            get.setText("Get!");
            get.setTextSize(8);




             //******************************************************************************// 
            //                              GET!                                    //  
           //******************************************************************************//

            get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){




                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    EditText x = new EditText (getApplicationContext());
                    x.setText(output);
                    table.addView(x);


                }

            });

             //******************************************************************************// 
            //                               END OF GET!                                //  
           //******************************************************************************//
```

Comment: You need to display the contents of textViews `txt` to `txt6`, in the EditText where you currently see a String's soft reference, right?

Comment: @Jave what does it mean?

Comment: you have not added any text to excellent.please add text to it and then retrieve it.

Comment: @Subin Sebastian i want the value of my edittext excellent to be display in my edittext x whenever i click the get button..

Comment: @krishna i want the value of my edittext excellent to be display in my edittext x whenever i click the get button

Comment: Beware you are also setting output to a string array, not a string. You need to say a[0] or a[1] depending on what you want

Comment: @Breadbin how can i do that?

Comment: please paste the code where you are setting text to excellent edittext which is missing here

Comment: instead of a, put a[0] or a[1] depending on which side of the split you want

Comment: do you want to receive the color of edittext ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things going wrong here.

1. you split on "," but that is not what you want. you want the `excellent.getText().toString();` of the `EditText`s
2. You append the text it is just after creation. It will be empty string at that time.

What you want to do

1. Make an `ArrayList` of `EditText`
2. Put all excellent `EditText`s in it.
3. In the `onClick` go through this list and append all the `getText().toString()` of these `EditTexts`

I won't give you an exact implementation. You should be able to figure that out on your own.

Comment: sir i made it this way  final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(int z=1;z<=count;z++){
     
    ArrayList<EditText> firstlist = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    firstlist.add(excellent);
    
    
    }    it only retrive the last input

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this

```
output.append(a+",");
```

Prints a representation of the object `a`, not the strings that `a` contains. Try somthing like this:

```
for(String s : a){
    output.append(s);
}
```

Comment: This is actually the answer to his problem. Next time he should post a more clear question...

Comment: @Simon Still i gives a null answer

Comment: Isn't your problem that you get `[Ljava.lang.String@40d3e4a8` instead of 3,2,5,1,4? Where do you get null?

Answer (score 0):

Your split function should be followed by a **FOR** loop. Split gives you a array.
So you need to iterate the array and append inside the lopp. Example

```
  String str = "one-two-three";

  for (String val: str.split("-", 2)){

      // Append your output with val here 

  }
```

Cheers